# Twitter Follow Link

Tags: twitter

How do I create a link that will automatically make a user follow a certain Twitter user if they're logged in or send them to Twitter to login first if they're not? I had found how to do this about month or 2 ago but can't find it again. I think it was something basic like a link or a form post to something like twitter.com/[user]/follow.

I've looked at the API, but I'd need the user to authenticate themselves on my site, and I don't want to deal with that. I just want them to authenticate directly on Twitter and not worry about it. The way I had found was nice and simple and I just want to find that again.

Comment: go check some right answers for your previous questions, and then we talk :P

Answer (score 31):

Use Twitter's [web intents](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/web-intents/overview).

While you can use [the follow button](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/follow-button/overview), you can also send users directly to the Intent URL, like so:

https://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=NASA

Comment: Link to web intents is gone. I propose [this replacement](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/follow-button/guides/web-intent-follow-button).

Comment: @showdev Appreciate it; I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[**how to use twitter api in my android application to implement follow button only**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590415/how-to-use-twitter-api-in-my-android-application-to-implement-follow-button-only)

**Android**

http://code.google.com/p/android-hackathon-in-fukuoka/source/browse/trunk/sodefuri/src/jp/jagfukuoka/sodefuri/TimeLineActivity.java?spec=svn167&r=167

**Code Snip:** (I have converted chines string into standard English)

```
public class TimeLineActivity extends ListActivity {
        private TwitterPreferenceManager tpm = new TwitterPreferenceManager(this);  

        private static final int FOLLOW = 1;
        private static final CharSequence FOLLOW_LABEL = "Follow";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                // timeline Obtaining process
                String screenName = getIntent().getStringExtra("screen_name");
                List<String> list = this.getTimeLine(screenName);

                setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.timeline_item,list));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                menu.add(0, FOLLOW, 0, FOLLOW_LABEL);
                return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case FOLLOW:
                        ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                        Configuration conf = builder.setOAuthAccessToken(tpm.getAccessToken())
                        .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(tpm.getAccessTokenSercret())
                        .setOAuthConsumerKey(TwitterPreferenceManager.CONSUMER_KEY)
                        .setOAuthConsumerSecret(TwitterPreferenceManager.CONSUMER_SERCRET)
                        .setDebugEnabled(true)
                        .build();
                        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(conf).getInstance();
                        try {
                                String screen_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("screen_name");
                                twitter.createFriendship(screen_name);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Was to follow.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (TwitterException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        break;

                default:
                        break;
                }
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        /**
         * Get the time line for the specified user
         * 
         * @param screenName
         * @return
         */
        private List<String> getTimeLine(String screenName) {
                List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

                Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
                ResponseList<Status> userTimeline;
                try {
                        userTimeline = twitter.getUserTimeline(screenName);
                        for (Status status : userTimeline) {
                                result.add(status.getText());
                        }
                } catch (TwitterException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return result;
        }
}
```

**iPhone**

http://www.chrismaddern.com/twitter-follow-button-for-ios-iphone-code/

Here is the way, How todo

The ***FollowMeButton*** can be created in Interface Builder by adding a UIButton and changing it's class to FollowMeButton or in code using the custom initialiser:

```
[self.view addSubview:[[FollowMeButton alloc] initWithTwitterAccount:@"chrismaddern" atOrigin:CGPointMake(205, 248) isSmallButton:YES]];
```

Two size modes are available controlled by setting isSmallButton in the initialiser or by later change the isSmall property of the object.