# how to use twitter api in my android application to implement follow button only

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-follow

Hi Guys I have gone through various links over twitter implementation.

I'm successfully able to tweet and get my followers from twitter. Now the next task is to follow us functionality of twitter in my app. Can anyone tell me the simple way to implement it.

I'm stuck from last one day. Not able to get rid of this. Please dont take this question for voting down and various things. It would be great if someone can provide me any sample code url and straight way answer to it.

Here's the links I have gone through:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/follow-button

[Android, Twitter, 'FOLLOW US'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752387/android-twitter-follow-us)

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/9515

https://code.google.com/p/android-hackathon-in-fukuoka/source/browse/trunk/sodefuri/src/jp/jagfukuoka/sodefuri/TimeLineActivity.java?spec=svn167&r=167

Please help me to get rid of this problem.

harry

Comment: Have you solved it? I am stuck implementing the same thing

Comment: @aditya a new answer is posted few minutes ago. Go and check it out. Might be this works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find out solution. I am successfully able to follow any user. Following is link that is working absolutely fine.
http://code.google.com/p/android-hackathon-in-fukuoka/source/browse/trunk/sodefuri/src/jp/jagfukuoka/sodefuri/TimeLineActivity.java?spec=svn167&r=167

CODE:--

```
    new TwitterTestAsync().execute(); // CALL THIS CLASS IN YOUR MAIN (CREATE) METHOD.
    private class TwitterTestAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try{
            doTwitterTask();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
    private void doTwitterTask(){
    screenName  =   "chetan_bhagat";
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
    .setOAuthConsumerKey("WRITE HERE YOUR CONSUMER KEY")
    .setOAuthConsumerSecret("WRITE HERE YOUR CONSUMER SECRET KEY")
    .setOAuthAccessToken("WRITE YOUR TOKEN STRING")
    .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("WRITE YOUR TOKEN SECRET STRING");
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();                 

    try {


        twitter.createFriendship(screenName);

    } catch (TwitterException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: procedure has to be
1. Login (If user not logged in to twitter already)
2. Then follow required page...

I'm not able to give login to user... plz help

Answer (score 2):

Use following code on your Custom Follow Button click event -

```
     TwitterFollow apiClient = new TwitterFollow(session);
            apiClient.getFollowService().create("Screen_Name_of_person_to_follow", null, true, new Callback<User>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Result<User> result) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Thanks for following!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error following", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

And create TwitterFollow class as -

```
public class TwitterFollow extends TwitterApiClient {
public TwitterFollow(TwitterSession session) {
    super(session);
}
public FollowService getFollowService() {
    return getService(FollowService.class);
}

public interface FollowService {
    @POST("/1.1/friendships/create.json")
    public void create(@Query("screen_name") String screen_name, @Query("user_id") String user_id, @Query("follow") boolean follow, Callback<User> cb);
}
```

}